# Django manage=False and relationships

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

For example i have two models in same DB

```
# one managed by other app
class Package(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    # ....
    class Meta:

        managed = False # !
        db_table = 'package'

# and one managed by django
class CustomPackage(models.Model):
    package = models.OneToOneField(Package, related_name='+', null=True, default=None)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # more fields ...
```

But once i use CustomPackage or Package instance i got error:

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "ckanwrap_custompackage" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."featured", "myapp__custompackage"."photo" FROM "myapp_...
```

Same in django admin. It was alright when i have some play-data, but when i move to postgresql -- this error appeares.

Django ORM doesn't create relationship table if one of models has `manage=Flase` in Meta?

Comment: No. There isn't a linking table in a one to one relationship anyway. Did you make and run migrations?

Comment: yup, i make clean migrations for each app and run migrate.

Comment: Looks like i messed up migrations and some dependencies. In case you have similar problem you should rapidly check database tables and problem models. Cheers!